# unity member modifier public must precede

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

### I already about fixed this issue, but right when things got crazier I realized how stupid it was to try and accomplish this since it clearly in the end has no benefit.

### Feel free to look over this still if you are having a similar issue, maybe you'll learn a thing or two. Idk ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

People have asked this before me on this site, but **none of them are really the same issue.** I'm sure that I probably missed something when I checked my code but I can't figure out what it is. Now Unity is bugging me about me supposedly not putting the *public* modifier in the right spot even though it's exactly where it should be, from what I'm seeing.

Let me show you real quick...

---

**The error Unity returns to me:**

```
Assets\saveFiles.cs(15,1): error CS1585: Member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name
```

---

**My code** (I'm kinda insane to post this long chunk here, just ignore those comments that I'm obviously too lazy to delete. That's for when I get further in development.)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Permissions; // Allows permission requests from within         script. VERY IMPORTANT.
using System.Security.AccessControl; // Also as important for the same reason.

[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class FileIOPermission{}(AllAccess View, string MyDocuments) // Grants access to the User's Documents folder.

public class saveFiles : MonoBehaviour {
    [DllImport("System.Windows.Forms.dll")]
    private static extern void SystemWindows();
    [DllImport("System.Drawing.dll")]
    private static extern void SystemDrawing();

    public string MyDocuments = System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) );

    // Reserve these variables for save file memory.
        public string UserData;
        public string UserConfig;
        public bool IsUserAvailable;

    void Start () {
        // On game execution, check for the game's configuration files. Load if they exist, save blank ones if they don't.
        // (Don't save in the Steam client's user data directory until you are aware of a way to find which user is logged into Steam.)

    // Check for saved progress and load it into memory if available. If not, it creates one and prepares it for editing.
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "user.sav") == true) {
            UserData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "user.sav");
        } else {
            System.IO.File.Create(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "user.sav");
            UserData = "statsA{\"xp\" : 0, \"money\" : 2000, \"MatchInProgress\" : false} Inventory{\"Default\":1;} loadout{1 null null null null}";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "user.sav", UserData);
            // Rules for UserData string:
            //      Inventory is stored as: "[ItemTag string]:[QuantityOfItem integer];"
            //
            //    Optionally, you can add extra info about the item from within a parentheses, placed after [ItemTag]. Useful for upgrades and equipment, leveling up, etc.
            //     (e.g. "Default(  [JSON METADATA]  ):1;")
            //
            //      Anything in quotes is a string, otherwise it is an integer or a boolean value depending on the returned value.
            //  (e.g. 24 as an integer, true/false/null as a boolean)
            //
            //      Loadout section is stored as 5 different inventory slot numbers, seperated by spaces.
            //  Each number represents which item listing, counting from the start to the end of the Inventory string.
            //  (e.g. "Inventory{weaponA:1;weaponB:1;weaponC:1;weaponD:1;} loadout{1 3 4 null null}" 
            //  will return WeaponA in slot 1, weaponC in slot 2, weaponD in slot 3, and slots 4 and 5 empty)
            //
            //      Majority of user save data will use JSON format or one of a similar syntax.
            //      (This applies to pretty much 100% of the settings file.)
        }

    // Check for user settings and load it into memory if available. If not, it creates one and prepares it for editing.
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "cfg") == true){
            UserConfig = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "cfg");
        } else {
            System.IO.File.Create(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "cfg");
        };
    }
    public void saveUsr() {
        // Code for Windows Standalone:
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "user.sav", UserData);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) ) + "/SaveData/tanky bois/" + "cfg", UserConfig);
    }

}
```

So in this situation here, how come Unity starts going nuts asking me to add a **"public"** modifier where there already is one?

And if I missed something then let me know.

**Thank you.**

Comment: Can you highlight the line that is being complained about.

Comment: My guess is you are missing something from, public sealed class FileIOPermission{}(AllAccess View, string MyDocuments), like a semicolon or something.

Comment: The error says line 15 character 1. It's talking about the FileIOPermission Constructor. (I know Unity doesn't natively support Constructors, so I installed a plugin that added those)

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper And I already tried the semicolon, doesn't fix anything but instead it just gives me tons more errors.

Comment: and if you remove [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]

Comment: You just need to tinker with it. Good luck.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper Wait, do you think that might fix it?
I've tinkered with it all I can right now. Been trying all sorts of different things for the past few hours.

Comment: Why are you using `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in Unity?

Comment: @Programmer Oh, yeah... right. I was gonna use it so I could assign the inputs/keystrokes differently because there wasn't any keybind reference on the Unity API reference that told me what the names of the keys were to the engine. I stop using it immediately once I realized I could just use the Input Handlers for things like "submit" or "fire" with at least some hint as to what to call each key in the settings. While I was experimenting with that, I left the libraries for it in the scripts just incase I needed it for something else (something not obsolete like what I was trying to do.)

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper **Just tried your suggestion that I should delete "[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]" and it litterally changed absolutely nothing.**

Comment: Remove lines 12 & 13 (or move them to below the class on line 15).

Comment: **Found this on experts-exchange.com. Does it sound legit or no??**
*"Sometimes the compiler issues really strange errors for things that are actually caused by other problems. Here's a few ideas that may cause freak-errors: ...

 - You haven't included your code within a namespace"*

Comment: @Neil No, doesn't work. It just gives me *"Assets\saveFiles.cs(70,74): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods."* And I want to leave that there since I've been having issues with saving to the Documents folder and I'm doing whatever I can to fix all this so I can see if it has any effect.

Comment: So you moved those lines and the error followed them ?? Hmm, I wonder if it's got something to do with those lines ...

Comment: @Neil It didn't exactly *follow* them, but more like it just caused a different and even bigger error that was pretty obvious from glancing at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's reformat your code to be easier to read:

```
....
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class FileIOPermission
{
}

(AllAccess View, string MyDocuments) // Grants access to the User's Documents folder.

public class saveFiles : MonoBehaviour {
....
```

Can you see the problem now?

`(AllAccess View, string MyDocuments)` is not in any class, so the compiler is trying to figure out what that means, and it thinks you are trying to declare a class or an interface or an enum, and it's best guess is that you are missing a modifier.

it looks to me like you have copied and pasted this line by mistake from somewhere else.  You should remove it.

Comment: Yeah, I have. I was going to replace that with something, but after tinkering around with the "string MyDocuments" the most so Unity would stop complaining about it being unexpected (this is why I sorta don't like the way variables are implemented into C#.) But after that I thought it would cause any issues because Unity right then stopped having errors, until later when this showed up. **Thanks for pointing this out, I'll try and clean it up and declare it first.**

Comment: The moral of the story is: error messages are a guess about what the user was thinking when they wrote broken code. If the user was *not thinking* when they wrote the broken code -- because there's a copy-paste mistake say -- then the error message can be super unhelpful.

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah, true.

Well either I need to tweak it some more still or I just somehow killed one bug and made another. What is life. xd...   **now it says the same error again but this time it's moved down to "public class saveFiles : MonoBehaviour {"**

Comment: @user9259829: It is a bad user experience for you to get a hundred parse errors, all of which disappear when you fix the first one. It's also a bad user experience to see only one error when you've got two.  Compiler designers have learned that users are more irritated by the former than the latter, so many compilers give up after the first error.  The Microsoft C# compiler error strategy is considerably more sophisticated than that, but there is not room in this comment to explain how.

Comment: @user9259829: The way to fix this problem is to *understand the code that you are editing*, and also *stop randomly adding or deleting stuff and hoping for the best*. This is an engineering problem; use engineering discipline.  Approach the problem carefully and analytically.